# SSH to another host via different user

Tags: linux, authentication, ssh

I need to SCP some files without password. I am confusing myself over the SSH authentication.Below is the scenario

Host: server1
User: user1 (Has access on server1)

Host: server2
user: user2 (Has access on server2)

So how do I setup the ssh handshake between the two users and on which server?

Comment: Do you want to copy files from server1 to server2?

Comment: Yes, i need to copy files from server1 to server2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to push your keys for the user on the client (doing the copying) to the user account on the host (receiving the files).

So if you want server2's user2 to copy to user1 on server1:

```
# logged in as user2 on server2
ssh-copy-id user1@server1
```

Or the other way around:

```
# logged in as user1 on server1
ssh-copy-id user2@server2
```

Enter your password when prompted, the keys should then be copied.

Then you can test:

```
ssh user1@server1 # should log in with no password to server1 as user1
```

Comment: unfortunately I dont have the password.We just use ssh keys

Comment: In that case, you just need to manually copy your public key `ssh-rsa AAAAB....RXte` to the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file on the server you want to log into without a password in the user's home directory.